# Retrieving sub table data as one column for the main table

Tags: mysql

I have main Table ( orders that have id , name ,...etc) and a sub table ( order_details that have order_id,box_number ) and the data is as follows

orders

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | test |
| 2 | test2 |

order_details

| id | order_id | box_number |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 44 |
| 2 | 1 | 58 |
| 3 | 2 | 44 |
| 4 | 2 | 78 |

I want to retrieve data as follows :

| id(from orders table ) | name | box_numbers |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | test1 | 44,58 |
| 2 | test2 | 44,78 |

i need a query in mysql to retrive as above , thanks for your help

I tried with this query , but no luck :

```
SELECT orders.*,GROUP_CONCAT(order_details.box_number ORDER BY order_details.id SEPARATOR ', ') AS boxes
FROM order_details AS sub_table JOIN orders  ON orders.id = sub_table.order_id
GROUP BY order_details.order_id`
```

Comment: Can you describe what *but no luck* means?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using aliasses for your table, you have to use it in the `SELECT` and `GROUP_BY` clause too instead of the real table name:

```
SELECT orders.*,GROUP_CONCAT(sub_table.box_number ORDER BY sub_table.id SEPARATOR ', ') AS boxes  
FROM order_details AS sub_table JOIN orders  ON orders.id = sub_table.order_id 
GROUP BY sub_table.order_id
```

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/urBiguAW16MMRwN3KwisXD/0